# JBoss with HotSwap agent

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, hotswap

Has anyone used JBoss AS 7.1 with DCEVM and HotSwap agent in production? Any tutorial anywhere? Is it possible to add new packages/classes through HotSwap agent, or just to replace existing ones?

I'm sorry the question is so vague. I'm merely researching proposed technologies.

Another point: do I have to deploy as exploded .war always, and replace/add .class files inside it?
Or can I deploy as zipped .war and copy additional zipped .jars alongside it?

My architecture is that I have a servlet and then additional components need to be accessible from it. These components I want to add/replace at runtime.

Comment: DCEVM is not intended for production enviroment. DCEVM is not unfortunately stable enough for this.

Comment: thanks for the comment; for production I intend to use dynamic class loading; I'll use DCEVM for development only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this moment not is possible, there is an open issue [Jboss support #27](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/issues/27):

> **JBoss 7 use OSGI** classloading and hence agent core classes are not
>   available from application classloader (this is not the case with
>   standard classloaders with parent delegation).
>
> The solution would be to add
>   `-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.hotswap.agent` to older agent versions (similar to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-895).
>
> However Hotswap agent now sets all necessary properties for JBoss on
>   startup.

And this:

> Currently, **JBoss 7 starts correctly, but ignores configuration
>   properties (extraClasspath, watchResources, webappDir)**. Hotswap via
>   debugging is still available, but you are unable to use alternative
>   source base.
>
> OSGI classloading must be `"hacked"` to allow all properties. See
>   Jetty/Tomcat plugin for similar implementation.